# How to trigger a patch event with inline HTMX tags when a Bootstrap 5 carousel-item becomes active inside a carousel?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5, htmx

So I am trying to trigger a HTMX patch request with an assigned id whenever an item in a Bootstrap5 carousel becomes an active item.

I know that its possible with a bit of extra scripting, but was wondering if purely doable with HTMX tags.

I have tried it with the HTMX *revealed & intersect options*, but these would all trigger at the same time when the page loads.

For example:

```
<div class="carousel-inner">
    <div id="6ec3f558-8526-4a3f-b70a-aeacf052805b"     
        hx-patch="/projects/6ec3f558-8526-4a3f-b70a-aeacf052805b/"     
        hx-trigger="revealed"     
        hx-swap="none">         
        <a href="/projects/6ec3f558-8526-4a3f-b70a-aeacf052805b/">         
            <div class="carousel-item active">         
            </div>     
        </a> 
    </div>   
    <div id="f2b061f3-3ccc-42aa-8217-c1194cdf4f00"     
        hx-patch="/projects/f2b061f3-3ccc-42aa-8217-c1194cdf4f00/"     
        hx-trigger="revealed"     
        hx-swap="none">     
        <a href="/projects/f2b061f3-3ccc-42aa-8217-c1194cdf4f00/">           
            <div class="carousel-item">         
            </div>       
        </a> 
    </div>
</div>
```

I have also experiment with trying to listen to [Bootstrap Carousel Events](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/components/carousel/#events), but didn't find or achieve the desired results.

Is there another solution that I am missing here from the HTMX documentation for a pure inline HTML tag approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After going back to this problem I ended up finding a solution that works.

```
<div id="project-carousel" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
    ...
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div id="6ec3f558-8526-4a3f-b70a-aeacf052805b"     
            hx-patch="/projects/6ec3f558-8526-4a3f-b70a-aeacf052805b/"     
            hx-trigger="slid.bs.carousel[to == 1] from:#project-carousel once"   
            hx-swap="none">         
            <a href="/projects/6ec3f558-8526-4a3f-b70a-aeacf052805b/">         
                <div class="carousel-item active">         
                </div>     
            </a> 
        </div>   
        <div id="f2b061f3-3ccc-42aa-8217-c1194cdf4f00"     
            hx-patch="/projects/f2b061f3-3ccc-42aa-8217-c1194cdf4f00/"     
            hx-trigger="slid.bs.carousel[to == 2] from:#project-carousel once"  
            hx-swap="none">     
            <a href="/projects/f2b061f3-3ccc-42aa-8217-c1194cdf4f00/">           
                <div class="carousel-item">         
                </div>       
            </a> 
        </div>
    </div>
    ...
</div>
```

The key was to listen to the proper element as `slid.bs.carousel` was called from outer carousel class and after that you just have to filter for the `to` parameter from the event.